# google analytics code on landing page and cookie law

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, seo

New EU cookie law do not allow page to set cookies on first load and until user make any action, scroll is consider as implicit acceptance

I'm not sure if

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

is enough to allow google analytics to be considered as non profiling cookie

how can i activate google analytics after page load?
monitoring with jQuery page scroll?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about EU laws and Google analytics and not strictly programing.

Comment: you might want to try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure, but to solve the issue it may be necessary to trigger analytics via javascript / jQuery on page scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### GA opt-out

You can allow people to opt-out from web tracking. It is made via cookie
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout

```
<a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Click here to opt-out of Google Analytics</a>

<script>
// Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXX-Y';

// Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
  window[disableStr] = true;
}

// Opt-out function
function gaOptout() {
  document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
  window[disableStr] = true;
}
</script>
```

### Load tracking on demand after cookie usage confirmation

If you want to firstly ask, if users agree to use tracking cookies, then you can postpone GA tracking to some trigger. Trigger can be e.g. cookieBar.

If you use jQuery, this should be very nice solution for you:
http://www.primebox.co.uk/projects/jquery-cookiebar/

Or

http://cookiesdirective.com/